# Unregister Instance in Unity container

Tags: .net, unity-container

How can i unregister instance in unity container.

I sure that it possible, but can't find solution in manual docs

Comment: I don't think you can't. You need to prevent that type from being registered.

Comment: Can you explain the context of why you need to unregister?

Comment: yes. i have hiearachy of containers..SystemSessionContainer-> AssemblerSessionContainer->Assembler1,Assembler2->SystemPluginContainer..
in SystemSession container i register Dictionary<String,String> instance that contain private information(superlogin etc) and  i don't want this information can seen in SystemPluginContainer..so after initializing all assemblers i want unregister Dictionary with system information

Comment: In such case you need separate container for this `Dictionary` which will not be hierarchical.

Answer (score 10):

There is no unregister. You can register a new instance on top of an existing one, and it'll replace the previous one with the newly registered instance.

Comment: You can, however, associate a lifetime manager with the registered instance and coerce Unity into evicting the registration by expiring/removing via the lifetime manager. +1 because there is no api to Unregister an instance. Please see [SO#2705418](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705418) for good examples of using a lifetime manager.