# how to destroy all data on the page when leave the page

Tags: wpf, prism

I use the prism.Unity (WPF).

I show a image in ViewA, And I want to Delete the image in ViewB

When I jump from ViewA to ViewB and delete this image

The Vistual Studio tip:  `The process cannot access the file '...\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Images\1.png' because it is being used by another process.`

**In other words, the image(Xaml) data of viewA is not been destroyed，** **What should I do？**

```
// App.Xaml.cs
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ViweA>();
containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<ViweB>();

// ViewAViewModel.cs

_regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "ViweB");
```

[ViewA and ViewB Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLOJU.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prism DI container - dispose unnecessary objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43936976/prism-di-container-dispose-unnecessary-objects)

Comment: @Rekshino , Thank you, but it can't solve my problem