# Can I un-register types in Unity IoC?

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

We have a library with a common Unity set-up which registers loads of basic types used throughout our codebase. Then each application calls this, and also registers additional app-specific types.

I've just run into the case where my application wants to override an interface type registration with a different implementing class. I can't see Unregister or Replace methods on the Unity Container... is this possible? If not how do I work around it?

Comment: Like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705418/how-to-removeunregister-registered-instance-from-unity-mapping

Comment: That seems to be talking about registered instances not types, but I'm not very familiar with unity

Comment: Just re-register and you will overwrite the previous one.

Comment: Instead of replacing registrations, you can also omit the registration in the common registration part. This way your end applications can each fill in the 'hole'.

Comment: Are you sure about that @crowcodet?

Comment: If you are asking me, then yes I am sure. I count on it in unit tests because I run my normal registrations then replaced mocked ones as needed.

Comment: Interesting, because i thought you could register multiple types against an interface.

Comment: You can but you have to provide a name parameter if you do that.

Comment: @Crowcoder weird... in my case it's trying to resolve the first registered type.