# Unregister service from unity

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using Unity within my application. For one integration test, we want to change one of the service registered to the application(because it would require some hardware).

So, I'm able to Register the new "mock" type, but I'm unable to remove the other implementation registered for this interface.

Also to mention, currently we register a "list" of this interface(it's some kind of driver) and we would like to remove all the others instance.

Any idea how I could do this?

Comment: Get a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705418/how-to-removeunregister-registered-instance-from-unity-mapping

Comment: @aelbouachri Hi, I already read this, but since in the real application, this needs to be a singleton, I cannot do it like this.

Comment: @J4N if it is an integration test then just do not register the unwanted types when arranging/setting up the test. Without a [mcve]  not much help/advise can be provided.

Comment: @NKosi: We have all this in configured in an app.config, and I was wanting to have the exact same modules except the one we have to mock. Like this it would ensure that if one day we introduce a regression because of adding a wrong implementation, our tests would fails.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to reuse the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) between your production app and your test app. This whole problem goes away if you avoid [composition root reuse](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2015/01/06/composition-root-reuse/). In theory, it sounds like you are gaining something by reusing the same configuration, but in practice it is rarely worth it. The composition root *is* your application config. Your test application is a *different* application and therefore should have its own composition root.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override the registration with either mocks, or a blank implementation. In the case of named registrations, it will work as long as you register with the same name. As you add a new registration, Unity will ignore the former registrations.

In our UnitTesting projects, we currently add all the regular registrations, then in the setup we register mocks on top of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are not using Container.IsRegistered in your tests (which is not always a valid assumption).

A similar approach to @Tipx answer is to re-register but provide an `InjectionMember` that will clear all of the policies associated with the type.  This has the benefit that, since the policy configuration has been removed, Unity should work as if the types were never registered (even though they will appear in the Registrations list).

Here's the `InjectionMember` ClearAllPolicies which clears the policies:

```
public class ClearAllPolicies : InjectionMember
{
    public override void AddPolicies(Type serviceType, Type implementationType, string name, IPolicyList policies)
    {
        var serviceTypeBuildKey = new NamedTypeBuildKey(serviceType, name);
        policies.Clear<IBuildKeyMappingPolicy>(serviceTypeBuildKey);

        var buildKey = new NamedTypeBuildKey(implementationType, name);

        policies.Clear<IBuildKeyMappingPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<IConstructorSelectorPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<IBuildPlanCreatorPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<IBuildPlanPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<IMethodSelectorPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<IPropertySelectorPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<ILifetimeFactoryPolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<ILifetimePolicy>(buildKey);
        policies.Clear<IBuilderPolicy>(buildKey);

        DependencyResolverTrackerPolicy.RemoveResolvers(policies, buildKey);
    }
}
```

Here's an example where 3 `ILogger` named implementations are registered and a list of `ILogger`s is resolved.  Then the polices are cleared for the loggers and a check is done to ensure that `ILogger` can't be resolved:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

container.RegisterType<ILogger, MyLogger>("Logger1");
container.RegisterType<ILogger, MyLogger>("Logger2");
container.RegisterType<ILogger, MyLogger>("Logger3");

// Resolve list of all loggers
var loggers = container.Resolve<ILogger[]>();

// Remove Policies for all ILoggers using ClearAllPolicies
foreach (var registration in container.Registrations
                                      .Where(r => r.RegisteredType == typeof(ILogger)))
{
    container.RegisterType(
       registration.RegisteredType,
       registration.MappedToType, 
       registration.Name, 
       new ClearAllPolicies());
}

// Ensure that when we try to resolve an ILogger or list of ILogger's that
// an exception is thrown
Assert.Throws<ResolutionFailedException>(() => container.Resolve<ILogger>("Logger1"));
Assert.Throws<ResolutionFailedException>(() => container.Resolve<ILogger>("Logger2"));
Assert.Throws<ResolutionFailedException>(() => container.Resolve<ILogger>("Logger3"));
Assert.Throws<ResolutionFailedException>(() => container.Resolve<ILogger[]>());
```

### Caveats & Warnings

- Do not use this in production code -- I would only use this for testing purposes
- It's possible that this does not capture all of the applicable policies and is not complete or does not work for every edge case (e.g. Interception or other esoteric scenarios)