# Unregister View and ViewModel in Prism.Unity.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, unity-container, prism

I am using Prism with Unity container for my Xamarin Forms application.

where I am registering my pages like this

```
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewType,ViewModelType>();
```

sometimes

```
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewType>();
```

Now I want to Unregister some of the registered pages along with their ViewModel.

Something like

```
Container.UnRegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewType>();
```

But can't figure out a way for it. need help.

**So far I have tried this,**

```
ContainerRegistration registrationContainer = Container.Registrations.FirstOrDefault(obj => obj.MappedToType == GetPageType(pageType));
if (registrationContainer?.LifetimeManager!=null)
{
    registrationContainer.LifetimeManager.RemoveValue();
}
```

with no luck.

**Reason why I want to Unregister...**

I have two views

```
Project.Namespace1.ViewA
Project.Namespace2.ViewA
```

Now I want to open `Project.Namespace1.ViewA` is some cases, and `Project.Namespace2.ViewA` in other cases.

This can be done as

```
NavigationService.NavigateAsync("ViewA");
```

It navigates to last view registered in Unity container.
That's why I want to unregister previous view before registering new view.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Unregistering a view will not hide it, nor will unregistering a view model dispose anything.

Comment: There is no out of the box unregister method for Unity.  You could take a look at this answer for clearing out registrations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44361488/114664 . However, I agree with @Haukinger that this is probably not a good idea.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have updated my question with reason behind unregistering views. hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should navigate to `Project.Namespace1.ViewA` and `Project.Namespace2.ViewA` (or some other unique names).

`RegisterTypeForNavigation` takes an optional string argument for the name, so pass an unique name for each of your views. When navigating to `ViewA` you should then navigate to the concrete `ViewA` you want to navigate to. If you absolutely need to emulate the register-unregister-behavior, create a service that holds the currently active `ViewA`.

Example:

```
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Project.Namespace1.ViewA,ViewModelType>( "ViewA1" );
Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<Project.Namespace2.ViewA,ViewModelType>( "ViewA2" );

interface IViewASelector
{
    string ViewA { get; set; }
}

// register Namespace1 and unregister Namespace2
_viewASelector.ViewA ="ViewA1";

// navigate to the active ViewA
NavigationService.NavigateAsync( _viewASelector.ViewA );
```

Probably, you also want an `enum` instead of a bunch of strings.

Comment: nice trick. I'll go with it for now. 
BTW, do you now any other ioc container which supports actual unregistration of type/instance?

Comment: probably ninject has this, as they have a lot of bizarre functionality ;-) and unity can do it, too, though manually, but unregistering feels like working against the container to me,